# PHP - Search array for string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, search, for-loop

I have a page with a form where I post all my checkboxes into one array in my database.
The values in my database looks like this: "0,12,0,15,58,0,16". 
Now I'm listing these numbers and everything works fine, but I don't want the zero values to be listed on my page, how am I able to search through the array and NOT list the zero values ?

I'm exploding the array and using a for each loop to display the values at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The proper thing to do is to insert a WHERE statement into your database query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value != 0
```

However, if you are limited to PHP just use the below code :)

```
   foreach($values AS $key => $value) {
      //Skip the value if it is 0
      if($value == 0) {
        continue;
      }

      //do something with the other values
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response it solved the issue I was dealing with, and had no clue I could solve it this easily. I guess I tend to over-complicate things from time to time.

Comment: Well, it's a common issue. I thing every programmer has this problem now and then. The thing is that code can always be more efficient, faster or simpler. Just take your time to look things up or ask it. Don't stare yourself to death on your code and pause. Its the best remedy :p

Answer (score 1):

In order to clean an array of elements, you can use the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) method.

In order to clean up of zeros, you should do the following:

```
function is_non_zero($value)
{
    return $value != 0;
}

$filtered_data = array_filter($data, 'is_non_zero');
```

This way if you need to iterate multiple times the array, the zeros will already be deleted from them.

Comment: In order to return the non-zero values I think it needs to be: return $value != 0;

Answer (score 0):

```
$String = '0,12,0,15,58,0,16';
$String = str_replace('0', '',$String); // Remove 0 values
$Array = explode(',', $String);
foreach ($Array AS $Values) { 
     echo $Values."<br>";
    }
```

Explained:

You have your checkbox, lets say the values have been converted into a string. using str_replace we have removed all 0 values from your string. We have then created an array by using explode, and using the foreach loop. We are echoing out all the values of th array minux the 0 values.

Comment: @MichaelThessel removed this. As the script is going to be exploding by a punctuation mark.. Then it will be removed automatically

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this. You can also specify a callback function in this function if you want to remove items on custom criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$out = array_filter(explode(',', $string), function ($v) { return ($v != 0); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of ways to do this, as is obvious from the answers above.

While this is not the best method, the logic of this might be easier for phpnewbies to understand than some of the above methods. This method could also be used if you need to keep your original values for use in a later process.

```
$nums = '0,12,0,15,58,0,16';
$list = explode(',',$nums);
$newList = array();
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    //
    // if value does not equal zero
    //
    if ( $value != '0' ) {
        //
        // add to newList array
        //
        $newList[] = $value;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $newList );
echo '</pre>';
```

However, my vote for the best answer goes to @Lumbendil above.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
$string = '0,12,0,15,58,0,16';
echo preg_replace(array('/^0,|,0,|,0$/', '/^,|,$/'), array(',', ''), $string); // output 12,15,58,16
```